# How to close and delete file in Java

Tags: java

I have written code that should be saved file in the local directory, create zip of that file, send email and delete both files (original and zip), So this is my code:

Method wich send email

```
public void sendEmail(Properties emailProperties, InputStream inputStream, HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
        try {
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(from, personal);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new SequelException(e.getMessage());
        }

            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(recipients);
            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(emailProperties.getProperty(PARAM_TITLE));             
            String message = emailProperties.getProperty(PARAM_EMLMSG);         
            mimeMessageHelper.setText(message);


            InputStreamSource inputStreamSource = null;
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStreamSource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
            } 

            String compressType = COMPRESS_TYPE_ZIP;
            String fileName = getAttachFilenameExtension(object, format);
            Path filePath = Paths.get(StrUtils.getProperty("temp.email.files.path") + "\\" + fileName);
            tempFile = saveTempFile(inputStreamSource.getInputStream(), filePath);
            if (tempFile.length() > 0) {
                inputStreamSource = compressFile(tempFile, filePath.toString(), compressType);
                fileName = StringUtils.substring(fileName, 0, StringUtils.lastIndexOf(fileName, ".")+1)  + compressType;
            }

            mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, inputStreamSource);
            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);


    } catch (MessagingException | IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new SequelException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(tempFile.getParentFile(), new WildcardFileFilter(
                FilenameUtils.removeExtension(tempFile.getName()) + "*"), null);
        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Save file in directory:

```
private File saveTempFile(InputStream inputStream, Path filePath) throws IOException {
    Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);
    Files.copy(inputStream, filePath);
    return new File(filePath.toString());
}
```

Compress file:

```
private InputStreamSource compressFile(File file, String filePath, String compressType) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = ZipFile(file, filePath);
    InputStreamSource inputStreamSource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
    return inputStreamSource;
}

public InputStream ZipFile(File file, String filePath) {
    String zipArchiveFileName = StringUtils.substring(filePath, 0, filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + COMPRESS_TYPE_ZIP;

    try (ZipArchiveOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new File(zipArchiveFileName));) {
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(StringUtils.overlay(file.getName(), "",
                StringUtils.lastIndexOf(file.getName(), "_"), StringUtils.lastIndexOf(file.getName(), ".")));
        zipOutput.putArchiveEntry(entry);
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);) {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {
                zipOutput.write(b, 0, count);
            }
            zipOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
        }

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(zipArchiveFileName);
        return is;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred while trying to compress file to zip", e);
        throw new SequelException(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

So the problem is when I try to delete files but zip file does not delete.
I am using Apache commons compress for zipping.
Can you help what's wrong?

Comment: I don't get your problem. Are you saying that the created zip file is not deleted in the end? Where is the code that should delete that file?

Comment: You need to provide the extension after compressing it . May be that cane be the reason its not deleting those compressed file.

Comment: `Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);` thats the deletion

Comment: EddyG delete part was written in finally  block

Answer (score 0):

For me this code is working perfectly. After compressing you may be trying to delete it without the extension(for eg .7z here).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kh1784\\Desktop\\Remote.7z");
    file.delete();
    if(!file.exists())
        System.out.println("Sucessfully deleted the file");
}
```

Output:-

> Sucessfully deleted the file

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I think stream not closed that's why the file has not been deleted, because when I try to delete file manually it alerts following message:
"The action cannot be completed because the folder is open in Java Platform SE binary"

Comment: @Suzan Yes, it must be closed before you try to delete.Try once after closing the stream . Stream will keep file open because of that it cant delete it.